# Баг с mysqli_connect и set_error_handler

Tags: php

Мы все знаем что запись типа:

```
@mysqli_connect($host,$username.'sd',$password,$db_name);
```

Или

```
mysqli_connect($host,$username.'sd',$password,$db_name) or die(‘Ошибка’);
```

позволяет нам отловить ошибку присоединения к БД

я в своем скрипите использую set_error_handler, и та функция что определена с помощью set_error_handler тоже не видишь ошибки, но когда в качестве обработчика ошибок предаю метод класса, то выше указанные методы отлова ошибок престают работать.

и я получаю ошибку вида:

```
E_WARNING

Описание: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'goodwebmaster'

Ошибка в файле: D:\Server\WAMP_Denewer\home\goodwebmaster\www\engine\classes\db.php

Номер строки: 19
```

Если кто знает как это решить подскажите…

код обработчика ошибок

```
<?php
class error {
    public function __construct() {

        set_error_handler(array(&$this,'error_php')); //Функция обработки ошибок PHP
        set_exception_handler(array(&$this,'exception_handler')); //Функция обработки исключений PHP
        register_shutdown_function(array(&$this,'fatal_error_php'));

    }

    private function error_php_message($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
        $errors=array(0=>'Exception',1=>'E_ERROR',2=>'E_WARNING',4=>'E_PARSE',8=>'E_NOTICE',16=>'E_CORE_ERROR',34=>'E_CORE_WARNING',64=>'E_COMPILE_ERROR',128=>'E_COMPILE_WARNING',256=>'E_USER_ERROR',512=>'E_USER_WARNING',1024=>'E_USER_NOTICE',2048=>'E_STRICT',4096=>'E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR',8192=>'E_DEPRECATED',16384=>'E_USER_DEPRECATED');

        $title='Ошибка PHP';
        $message='<p><strong>'.$errors[$errno].'</strong></p>
                  <p><strong>Описание:</strong> '. $errstr.'</p>
                  <p><strong>Ошибка в файле:</strong> '.$errfile.'</p>
                  <p><strong>Номер строки:</strong> '.$errline.'</p>';
        ms_die($title,$message);
    }

    public function error_php($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {    
        $this->error_php_message($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline);

        /*switch ($errno) { 
            case E_WARNING: 
            case E_USER_WARNING:

            break; 
        }  */
    }

    public function exception_handler($exception) {
        $trace = $exception->getTrace();
        $this->error_php_message(0, $exception->getMessage(), $trace[0]['file'], $trace[0]['line']);
    }

    public function error_db($errno,$errstr) {
        $title='Ошибка БД';
        $message='<p><strong>'.$errno.'</strong></p>
                  <p><strong>Описание:</strong> '. $errstr.'</p>';
        ms_die($title,$message);
    }

    public function fatal_error_php() {
        $error=error_get_last();
        switch ($error['type']) {
            case E_ERROR: 
                $this->error_php_message($error['type'], $error['message'], $error['file'], $error['line']);
            break; 
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Покажите код ваших обработчиков ошибок

Comment: добавил...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Пользовательский обработчик будет вызываться при любой ошибке, независимо от настроек, заданных функцией `error_reporting()`. Однако, вы можете прочитать текущее значение `error_reporting` и задать в обработчике соответствующие действия. В частности, это значение будет равно 0, если выражение, вызвавшее ошибку, начинается с оператора контроля ошибок @.

То-есть обработчик ошибки вызывается в любом случае, даже если есть собачка. Но, при установленной собачке `error_reporting()` вернёт 0. Вы можете в обработчике проверить это значение и в соответствии с этим выполнять вывод ошибки.

Comment: обработчик ошибки вызваться если ошибка добирается до него, а собачкой мы глушим такую ошибку и она не добирается до обработчика. Учите PHP луче!

Comment: Вы не правы. Обработчик вызывается в любом случае. Читайте третий абзац на [этой странице](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php).

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую следующий вариант:

```
set_error_handler('class_name::have_error');
@$db=new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$database);
if($db->connect_errno) trigger_error($db->connect_error,E_USER_ERROR);
```

P.S. die это слишком грубо, имхо

Comment: > Метод должен быть статическим

Не обязательно. Можно взять метод существующего объекта.

Comment: Да, действительно, можно передавать массив. Вызов в этом случае аналогичен `call_user_func()`

Comment: в статичном методе нельзя использовать $this